# loop div based on data obtained from php response

Tags: javascript, php, json

The data

```
[{"id":"1","title":"science","added":"today","updated":"today","api":"25213","access":"0"}
[{"id":"2","title":"commerce","added":"","updated":"","api":"","access":"0"}]
```

The code

```
var data = 
            [{"id":"1","title":"science","added":"today","updated":"today","api":"25213","access":"0"}][{"id":"2","title":"commerce","added":"","updated":"","api":"","access":"0"}];


        var htmlText = '';

        for ( var key in data ) {
            htmlText += '<div class="div-conatiner">';
            htmlText += '<p class="p-name"> Name: ' + data[key].title + '</p>';
            htmlText += '<p class="p-loc"> Location: ' + data[key].location + '</p>';
            htmlText += '<p class="p-desc"> Description: ' + data[key].description + '</p>';
            htmlText += '<p class="p-created"> Created by: ' + data[key].created_by + '</p>';
            htmlText += '<p class="p-uname"> Username: ' + data[key].users_name + '</p>';
            htmlText += '</div>';
        }

        $('body').append(htmlText);
```

this is the php response. i want to represent this data in html using js somehow how to do this

Comment: The data is not a valid JSON String!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes in your code. As @RiggsFolly already mentioned your json is invalid. Furthermore you need to parse the data string as json object. Have a look at this code.

```
var data = '[{"id":"1","title":"science","added":"today","updated":"today","api":"25213","access":"0"},{"id":"2","title":"commerce","added":"","updated":"","api":"","access":"0"}]';
var htmlText = '';

var data = JSON.parse(data);
for ( var key in data ) {
    htmlText += '<div class="div-conatiner">';
    htmlText += '<p class="p-name"> Name: ' + data[key].title + '</p>';
    htmlText += '<p class="p-loc"> Location: ' + data[key].location + '</p>';
    htmlText += '<p class="p-desc"> Description: ' + data[key].description + '</p>';
    htmlText += '<p class="p-created"> Created by: ' + data[key].created_by + '</p>';
    htmlText += '<p class="p-uname"> Username: ' + data[key].users_name + '</p>';
    htmlText += '</div>';
}

$('body').append(htmlText);
```

Since you are already using jQuery you could also create the div container in jQuery style.

```
var container = $('<div></div>').addClass('div-container');
```